# VB - Negative Number and Conditional Statement

Tags: vb.net

Back again with another noob question that is bugging the crap out of me. I spent 2 days trying figure this one out. It seems that me and VB and negative numbers always have a misunderstanding.

I got everything else in the program for a fat percentage calculator to work except the conditional statement that SHOULD print out an error message if either the double conversion of two textbox strings is less than zero. However, even though I enter negative numbers for both when testing, the program skips over my Else error statement and calculates the two negative numbers anyway and gets some wholly ridiculous fat percentage number. It doesn't even seem as if it's just going through with the expressions if the "If-Then" part of the code as I did the math and the percentage answer does not match up.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    'Declare variables
    Dim dblCaloriesInFood As Double
    Dim dblGramsOfFat As Double
    Dim dblPercentageOfCaloriesFromFat As Double
    Dim dblCaloriesFromFat As Double


    'Always initialize lblLowInFat message as not visible when button is clicked
    lblLowInFat.Visible = False

    Try
        'Converting textbox strings to double. 

        dblCaloriesInFood = CDbl(txtCaloriesInFood.Text)
        dblGramsOfFat = CDbl(txtGramsOfFat.Text)

        If dblCaloriesInFood Or dblGramsOfFat > 0 Then

            'Calculate Calories from fat
            dblCaloriesFromFat = dblGramsOfFat * 9

            'Calculate percentage of calories from fat
            dblPercentageOfCaloriesFromFat = dblCaloriesFromFat / dblCaloriesInFood

            'Display percentage of calories from fat
            If dblPercentageOfCaloriesFromFat >= 0 Then
                lblMessage.Text = dblPercentageOfCaloriesFromFat.ToString("p")
            Else
                lblMessage.Text = String.Empty
            End If

            'Display low fat message
            If dblPercentageOfCaloriesFromFat <= 0.3 And dblPercentageOfCaloriesFromFat > 0 Then
                lblLowInFat.Visible = True
            End If
        Else
            'really tried to make this message work but couldn't figure it out.
            'why does it only display this message when zero is entered and not when
            'negative numbers are entered. instead it just calculates the negative numbers
            'as if they were whole positive numbers or something, not sure because the percentage
            'is way off the charts when i enter negative numbers. can't figure this out.
           MessageBox.Show("Either the calories or fat grams were incorrectly entered")
            txtCaloriesInFood.Text = String.Empty
            txtGramsOfFat.Text = STring.Empty
            txtCaloriesInFood.Focus()

        End If

    Catch
        'error message for invalid input
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for calories in food & number of fat grams.")
        txtCaloriesInFood.Focus()
    End Try



End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `If` statement is wrong. First, you need to test the two values separately. Second, you want both values to be greater than zero, so you should use `And` instead of `Or` (which means only one has to be greater than zero).

```
If dblCaloriesInFood > 0 And dblGramsOfFat > 0 Then
```